# Check if list of lists in guard clause for Elixir

Tags: elixir

What is the best way to check if an argument is a list of lists in a guard clause, or a list of key-value pairs?

The solution I came up with just grabs the head and does a check, but I feel like there must be a better way.

```
def stuff(items) when is_list(hd(items)) do
    something
end
```

Comment: This doesn't check if `items` is a list of a list, it just checks the first value. It passes even when `items` were `[["a", "list"], "string", 123]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> but I feel like there must be a better way

Yes, there is. Use pattern matching like this:

```
def stuff([head | _]) when is_list(head) do
  something
end
```